# Does Time-based One Time Password improves security in case of database leak?

Tags: authentication, passwords, multi-factor

From what I understand, Time-based One Time Passwords used a seed and a mathematical algorithm to generate unique passwords. As the seed is known by the user (or the device used by the user), and the authentication server. 
However, this means that if the database is leaked, the seed will be known by the attacker.

As with a database leak, an attacker can know both the password and the OTP, does Time-based One Time Password improves security in case of database leak? Or is the goal of OTP only to prevent an attacker to authenticate when he knows the password by another way (another database leak, social engineering...)?

Comment: You may want answers focused on the scenario where both the password hashes and OTP seeds are leaked, but I thought I'd point out that the OTP seeds are often not stored in the same database as the hashes.  They probably will be in a different database on a dedicated authentication server or even hosted by a third party authentication service.  So the compromise of your password hashes doesn't necessitate a compromise of your OTP authentication in the real world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, password is what is supposed to protect the user in case your database leaks. If you **hash and salt properly**, the attacker should not be able to obtain plaintext version of the password (with reasonable password in reasonable time with reasonable resources, if an attacker such as the NSA is after you, don't rely on this. Also, if you know your database leaked or could have leaked, force users to change password to be sure). Your app should not accept the hash as a valid password. So the attacker should not be able to log in even if database is leaked. Note: If you want to hash on client side, check schemes such as [SCRAM-SHA256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7677) to protect form this kind of attack.

TOTP on the other hand protects from user password being leaked by the user, or otherwise obtained (brute-force, interception, keylogger) without compromising server.

If you want additional protection in case server is compromised AND password is obtained (for example attacker intercepts login requests and get the password that way), consider either using something like SCRAM to limit the password exposure to the server, or using [public-private key pair](https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm) for login, possibly with hardware token using [U2F](https://www.yubico.com/solutions/fido-u2f/).

Comment: With the right gear, even a strong hash will eventually be broken. The important part is to use hashing schemes that require an attacker to brute-force each password on an individual basis (random salts), and make it take as long as possible to do so (many iterations with a computationally expensive algorithm). For an individual user, it might be practical for an attacker to brute-force a password from the hash, but the whole database wouldn't be worth the effort.

Comment: @nbering Well, I took that as given when saying properly hashing and salting. While it is theoretically possible to still obtain single users password, there are very few if any practical situations, where that would be worth it to the attacker. But nice comment anyway.

Comment: I agree with the answer, I just wanted to add a point for context. Since the hashing is what protects the password, it needs to be taken seriously. Setting up 2fa but using unsalted md5 is not going to protect a user's account in the event of a database breach.

Comment: Please don't perpetuate the myth that _hashing and salting properly_ will completely protect passwords.  That does slow the attacker down, but it doesn't create the barrier against cracking you seem to think it does.

Comment: @PwdRsch I know it does not, but just answered elsewhere what it would take to crack 8 aplhanumerical characters long random password, that is well hashed. The NSA may be able to do it, but no ordinary attacker will. But edited to make it clear.

Comment: @PeterHarmann See [this benchmark](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40) about how fast hash can be done. SHA256 have a speed of 23012.1 MH/s. 8 characters with lowercase, uppercase and numbers have 62^8 combination. A single password can be done in less than three hours. Even if you use a much slower hash, like let's say bcrypt with a factor of 12, with around 800 Hash per seconds, check 1 million passwords take 20 minuts, so even if a brute force attack is impossible, a dictionary attack is possible.

Comment: @Kepotx Yes. If you have a weak password, it can be broken. But it is not hard to have good enough password: http://correcthorsebatterystaple.net/

Comment: sure, but with 1 million password entry, correcthorsebatterystaple is probably on the list, as P4ssw0rd, even if both have high enough entropy. A good password must have a good entropy for brute force but also be random enough to avoid dictionary attack

Comment: @Kepotx you probably don't understand entropy. 1234 has entropy of maybe 1-2 bits, because even though it is one of 10k possible numeric password, it would be one of the first attacker would try, as it is not random at all. A password generated by the site I provided on the other hand would have entropy strong enough to prevent even fast hashing attacks (if slow KDF was not used), because no reasonable dictionary could possibly contain it.

Comment: @Kepotx or you maybe misunderstood the link I sent. If it is the case, please disregard the above comment. The site generates a password, that is memorable by only using English words but sill random enough (enough entropy) to be very strong. I estimate at least 47 bits with the default settings.

Comment: @PeterHarmann I know this website, and also the XKCD comics. I think we agree on what's a good password, the only think i meant to say is that a password hash can be broken, even with "standard good practices" and a good enough hardware

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76593/discussion-between-peter-harmann-and-kepotx).